# (Catalano Framework) Image Comparison Algorithm

Tags: android, image-processing

First and foremost, thanks to Diego Catalano for his created algorithm libraries which has benefited many developers and programmers.

For the **Object Fidelity algorithm** as posted here: [Is there an algorithm to detect the differences between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499523/is-there-an-algorithm-to-detect-the-differences-between-two-images) , the *float* results for

- Number of Errors
- Number of Mean-Square Errors
- Number of Mean-Square Signal-to-Noise Errors,

how can I convert there errors to an accuracy percentage of the similarity extent between two images?

I have limited experience on image processing design and analysis and owing to this library can improve the functionality of a gallery comparison framework.

Gladly appreciate any advice or guidance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Eric, this link can help you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179019/how-to-compare-set-of-images-in-java-using-pixel-based-image-comparision-metric/21763781#21763781

Comment: In the version 1.3 contains derivative signal to noise ratio in the objective fidelity. If you need to compute the differences, you just need to compute the abs(errorTotal).